# How to get path for image inside ImageView

Tags: swift

There is an ImageView's list, each in its own cell in the tableView! My task is to upload all these images to the google drive server! But the problem is that the google drive API requires a downloadable filePath! Question: Can I upload images immediately from ImageView or do I need to save them to the camera roll?

Now the application takes a photo from the camera, puts it in the imageView and then when you click on the button, saves the image to the camera roll!

Comment: I would save them to the document directory and then delete them as the uploads complete.

Comment: Or to the App's temporary folder if you have document/file support enabled

Comment: Got you guys! Thank you!